# RabbitMQ - Whats the hostname when connecting remote server?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have just started to use rabbitmq, I am currently work on the tutorials on the rabbitmq website. I have done the hello world tutorial by using my local machine as my server. Now I want to connect to a remote server on a different machine. The question I have is what is the hostname I need to use to connect to this server. Is it the ip address of the machine the rabbitmq server is installed on.

```
            RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.HostName = "XXX.X.X.X";
            connectionFactory.UserName = "admin";
            connectionFactory.Password = "test";
            connectionFactory.VirtualHost = "vHost";
            connectionFactory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
            Connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

Comment: yes you can use the ip address of the server where rabbitmq is running.

Answer (score 5):

you can use remote IP address as HostName
use user's virtualhost as declared in RabbitMQ management panel
dont use "guest" user - this user can only use when HostName id localhost(not remotly) and dont create No Password User as user

```
RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = "10.62.28.139";
factory.UserName = "user";
factory.Password = "password";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
```